# Client side model equivalent of a server side orm parent model

Tags: aqueduct

Auto generation of client model based on server side open api 3.0 document does not produce the equivalent of server side orm parent class.

I'm developing a new aqueduct server, and want to have the browser client model automatically generated from the server side model. I created a LanguageLevel model class and a LanguageLesson model class where a LanguageLevel has many LanguageLesson. I created the two corresponding controllers and getAllLevels, createLanguageLevel and getAllLessons operations respectively. Then I created the migration file as well as the open api 3.0 document file. I used the open api generate utility to create the client side library.

This is for aqueduct CLI and project version 3.1.0+1. The result below was the same for version 3.0.2. For client model generation openapi-generator-cli-3.3.4 was used.

Server Side

class LanguageLevel extends ManagedObject<_LanguageLevel> implements _LanguageLevel {}

class _LanguageLevel {

```
@primaryKey
int pk;

@Column(unique: true)
int sequence;

ManagedSet<LanguageLesson> languageLessons;
```

}

class LanguageLesson extends ManagedObject<_LanguageLesson> implements _LanguageLesson {}

class _LanguageLesson {

```
@primaryKey
int pk;

@Column()
int sequence;

@Relate(#languageLessons)
LanguageLevel languageLevel;
```

}

open api 3.0 using command: aqueduct document

{
    "openapi": "3.0.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "back_end",
        "description": "Seven Arabic Server.",
        "version": "0.0.1"
    },
    "servers": [{
        "url": "http://localhost:8888"
    }],
    "paths": {
        "/levels": {
            "parameters": [],
            "get": {
                "tags": ["Levels"],
                "operationId": "getAllLevels",
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "sequence",
                    "in": "query",
                    "required": false,
                    "allowEmptyValue": false,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful response."
                    }
                }
            },
            "post": {
                "tags": ["Levels"],
                "operationId": "createLanguageLevel",
                "parameters": [],
                "requestBody": {
                    "required": true,
                    "content": {
                        "application/json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LanguageLevel"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful response."
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/levels/{sequence}": {
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "sequence",
                "in": "path",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }]
        },
        "/lessons": {
            "parameters": [],
            "get": {
                "tags": ["Lessons"],
                "operationId": "getAllLessons",
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "id",
                    "in": "query",
                    "required": false,
                    "allowEmptyValue": false,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful response."
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/lessons/{id}": {
            "parameters": [{
                "name": "id",
                "in": "path",
                "required": true,
                "schema": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }]
        },
        "/example": {
            "parameters": []
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "LanguageLesson": {
                "title": "LanguageLesson",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "pk": {
                        "title": "pk",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "description": "This is the primary identifier for this object.\n",
                        "nullable": false
                    },
                    "sequence": {
                        "title": "sequence",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "nullable": false
                    },
                    "languageLevel": {
                        "title": "languageLevel",
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "pk": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "description": ""
            },
            "LanguageLevel": {
                "title": "LanguageLevel",
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "pk": {
                        "title": "pk",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "description": "This is the primary identifier for this object.\n",
                        "nullable": false
                    },
                    "sequence": {
                        "title": "sequence",
                        "type": "integer",
                        "description": "No two objects may have the same value for this field.\n",
                        "nullable": false
                    },
                    "languageLessons": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LanguageLesson"
                        },
                        "nullable": true,
                        "readOnly": true
                    }
                },
                "description": ""
            }
        },
        "responses": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "requestBodies": {},
        "headers": {},
        "securitySchemes": {},
        "callbacks": {}
    }
}

Note languageLevel defined as an object type with "pk" property only and LanguageLevel defined as an object type with "pk", "sequence" and "languageLessons". Extracted from the spec they look like:

```
                "languageLevel": {
                    "title": "languageLevel",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "pk": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                }
```

and

```
        "LanguageLevel": {
            "title": "LanguageLevel",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "pk": {
                    "title": "pk",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "This is the primary identifier for this object.\n",
                    "nullable": false
                },
                "sequence": {
                    "title": "sequence",
                    "type": "integer",
                    "description": "No two objects may have the same value for this field.\n",
                    "nullable": false
                },
                "languageLessons": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LanguageLesson"
                    },
                    "nullable": true,
                    "readOnly": true
                }
            },
            "description": ""
        }
```

Open API Generated Client Side Model (just LanguageLevel shown)

class LanguageLevel {

```
int pk = null;
LanguageLevel();

@override
String toString() {
  return 'LanguageLevel[pk=$pk, ]';
}

LanguageLevel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null) return;
    pk = json['pk'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
       'pk': pk
    };
}

static List<LanguageLevel> listFromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    return json == null ? new List<LanguageLevel>() : json.map((value) => 
    new LanguageLevel.fromJson(value)).toList();
}

static Map<String, LanguageLevel> mapFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var map = new Map<String, LanguageLevel>();
    if (json != null && json.length > 0) {
        json.forEach((String key, dynamic value) => map[key] = new 
        LanguageLevel.fromJson(value));
    }
    return map;
}
```

}

Apart from all the necessary code, it created the LanguageLevel and LanguageLesson model classes as well. LanguageLesson model looks good as it has the expected properties and a reference to the LanguageLevel as well. However LanguageLevel only has the @primarykey equivalent of the server side model. So right now there is no way to display the LanguageLevel objects from the generated code. I expected to be able to do so by this stage.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to read with that formatting, but the models are defined in your schema components correctly. The languageLevel property in your LanguageLesson type is backed by foreign key column. The default behavior when you fetch a LanguageLesson will be to only have an object with the primary key populated.

If you are planning to have an endpoint where you join the full LanguageLevel object with LanguageLesson, then you need to override the OpenAPI response for that particular endpoint by overriding methods in ResourceController for document generation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Yes that formatting is not good. Sorry for that. Tried to reformat, but seems like didn't succeed. Anyway have extracted the two definitions of "languageLevel" and "LanguageLevel" under the schema. The only difference is the casing for "L". Wondering whether this is an openapi generation issue. When generating the "LanguageLevel" model it has preferred the "languageLevel" definition rather then the "LanguageLevel" definition. Will try out your instructions however.

Comment: Tried your instruction. I wasn't able to get the desired OpenAPI spec. Actually it was still the same as previous, no matter how simple I made the override for the documentOperationResponses method. Anyway it is quite a tedious process and kind of defeats the purpose, if I have to do this for every one to many relationship.

Comment: Just to reiterate, the issue here is not about the data. Aqueduct has very granular control through returningProperties method etc. Also I understand the need to stop circular references from the joined sets and objects. The issue is about the generated API specs by Aqueduct and the generated client library by openapi generator. Between the two I am unable to get a client class that is a parent in a one to many relationship in the Aqueduct ORM side. Note the missing properties in the client side LanguageLevel class supplied near the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by replacing the "languageLevel" specification with {"$ref": "#/components/schemas/LanguageLevel"} as per the Open API Specification 3.0.2. Now when I run the openapi-generate-cli against the specification file, I get the correct class LanguageLevel as follows:

class LanguageLevel {

```
int pk = null;
int sequence = null;

List<LanguageLesson> languageLessons = [];
LanguageLevel();

@override
String toString() {
    return 'LanguageLevel[pk=$pk, sequence=$sequence, languageLessons=$languageLessons, ]';
}

LanguageLevel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json == null) return;
    pk = json['pk'];
    sequence = json['sequence'];
    languageLessons = LanguageLesson.listFromJson(json['languageLessons']);
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'pk': pk,
      'sequence': sequence,
      'languageLessons': languageLessons
    };
}

static List<LanguageLevel> listFromJson(List<dynamic> json) {
    return json == null ? new List<LanguageLevel>() : json.map((value) => new LanguageLevel.fromJson(value)).toList();
}

static Map<String, LanguageLevel> mapFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var map = new Map<String, LanguageLevel>();
    if (json != null && json.length > 0) {
        json.forEach((String key, dynamic value) => map[key] = new LanguageLevel.fromJson(value));
    }
    return map;
}
```

}

I now have the sequence and languageLessons properties as well.

Since the open api specification file is being generated by Aqueduct, we can safely say this is an Aqueduct issue where, in the components section, it is creating a different parent definition within a child definition, instead of referencing the parent property to the already defined parent. (Note: However, it is referencing the child array property in the parent class to the defined child.)